# Derivatives of Continuously Parameterized Operators on Hilbert Spaces

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, mathematical-physics

I'm working through Ballentine's *Quantum Mechanics - A Modern Development* and I've reached a section of the book where he is looking at infinitesimal transformations and generators. To do this, he assumes a family of operators continuously parametereized by a variable $s$, $U(s)$, and expands around $s=0$ as $$U=I+\frac{dU}{ds}|_{s=0} +O^2(s).$$

I don't quite understand how these derivatives are defined. I understand that we can take limits in the Hilbert space, so my first thought is something like the derivative being defined by $$\frac{dU}{ds}|\psi\rangle = \lim_{\epsilon\to0}\left(\frac{U(s+\epsilon) - U(s-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}\right)|\psi\rangle$$
for all kets in the space. Then, if this converges with respect to the norm of the space, the derivative is defined.

Is this the right way to think about the derivative of an operation, with higher derivatives defined similarly? From here, I would assume we can talk about convergent series of operators to define the exponential. This seems to be the purview of functional analysis. Are there any recommended sources from which I could learn more about analysis with operators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is the right way to look at this except you need $U(s)$ instead of $U(s-\epsilon)$ in your formula.
If you have a map $s\mapsto U(s)$ into the set of bounded operators on a Hilbert (e.g., unitary operators), then you have two main approaches for defining the derivative
$$
\frac{d}{ds}U(s)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon}(U(s+\epsilon)-U(s))\ .
$$
This depends on the topology.

1) The operator norm topology: meaning the convergence in this limit is with respect to the operator norm. This is too restrictive for QM applications.

2) The strong operator topology: that's exactly what you said, i.e., the limit means that for every ket $|\psi\rangle$, you apply $\frac{1}{\epsilon}(U(s+\epsilon)-U(s))$
and see if this converges in the Hilbert space norm. In general it does not converge for every ket. So the derivative operator $\frac{d}{ds}U(s)$ typically is an unbounded operator which is only defined on a dense subspace of the Hilbert space. Look up [Stone's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups). Also, a good book to go more in depth into this is
["Quantum Mechanics and Quantum Field Theory
A Mathematical Primer"](https://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/physics/theoretical-physics-and-mathematical-physics/quantum-mechanics-and-quantum-field-theory-mathematical-primer?format=HB)
by Jon Dimock.

Comment: No. Look at any book on elementary single variable calculus. The derivative $f'(x)$ of a function is defined as $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon}$ and not as $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+\epsilon)-f(x-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}$. The same formula is used for operators, except one needs more work to interpret the formula correctly, with paying attention to the topology etc. Note that the definition of limit does not say $\epsilon$ is necessarily positive (perhaps the source of confusion).

Comment: Sorry, I deleted that comment because I wanted to add more, but accidentally posted it. I had originally said "Right, the limit is from both sides, so it makes sense that we only need $U(s-\epsilon)$"

I understand where my confusion was coming from. In my head, I was taking a two sided limit as $U$ approached $U(0)$ from positive and negative $s$. Thanks for reminding me of the correct way to formulate this. Visualizing $\epsilon$ as positive is where I made my mistake.

Comment: Look at the Wikipedia page for operator topologies, the norm topology is the strongest one. Why do we need a coarser topology? Do we have operators that we want to differentiate whose difference quotients do not converge in the norm topology due to how fine it is?

Comment: I'm glad that my definition was on track. The strong operator topology makes sense to me then. I am surprised to hear that $\frac{dU}{ds}$ is not a bounded operator, though. Rather than restricting its domain, could we make sense of it within a rigged Hilbert space $\Omega\subset H\subset\Omega^{\times}$? I understand that this approach can be used to facilitate the operators $x$ and $\partial_x$ which are also unbounded. 

Thank you for the recommendation! I'm going to try and find it asap.

Comment: The most important situation for your question is when $U(s)$ is unitary and satisfies $U(s+t)=U(s)U(t)$, i.e. one is dealing with a one-parameter semigroup of unitaries. Think for example the time evolution operators. The derivative essentially is the Hamiltonian. Even for the simplest physically interesting examples like the harmonic oscillator, this derivative $H$ is not defined for all kets in the Hilbert space $L^2$ but for a dense subspace, and the operator is unbounded. That's life.

Comment: Also, I would not invest time learning about rigged Hilbert spaces, but rather learn some standard spectral theory for unbounded operators together with the theory of Schwartz distributions.